# How to get screen origin (top-left point)?

Tags: c#, xna

I'm building a game and I want to find the top-left point of the window.

It's **not** (0,0) because the character is moving **AND THE CAMERA IS FOLLOWING HIM**.
I have to **find another way**, then, by calculating the point based on the character.

Maybe something's **already built** into XNA?

I added some photos:

1)https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytpV9.png

2)https://i.stack.imgur.com/rx71u.png

I need another way to do it.
Please tell me if you have an idea or if it's possible.

**Edit:**
Code of camera:

```
public class Camera
{
    public Matrix Mat { get; private set; }
    V2 pos;
    IFocus focus { get; set; }
    F zoom;
    Viewport vp;

    //ctor
    public Camera(IFocus focus , Viewport vp , F zoom)
    {
        this.focus = focus;
        this.zoom = zoom;
        this.vp = vp;
        this.pos = V2.Zero;
    }

    public void update()
    {
        Mat = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-pos.X, -pos.Y, 0) *
              Matrix.CreateRotationZ(0) * //-focus.Rot 
              Matrix.CreateScale(zoom , zoom , 1) * 
              Matrix.CreateTranslation(vp.Width / 2 , vp.Height / 2 , 0);
        this.pos = V2.Lerp(this.pos, focus.Pos, 0.97f); 
    }
```

drawing code:

```
class Drawing : IFocus
{
    #region Data
    protected T2 tex;
    protected V2 org;
    protected Rec? rec;
    public V2 Pos { get; set;}
    C color;
    public F Rot { get; set;}      
    protected V2 scale;
    protected SE se;
    F layer; 
    #endregion
    //Rec? - can be NULL
    #region ctor
    public Drawing(T2 tex, V2 pos, Rec? rec, C color, F rot, V2 org, V2 scale, SE se, F layer)
    {
        this.tex = tex;
        this.Pos = pos;
        this.rec = rec;
        this.color = color;
        this.Rot = rot;
        this.org = org;
        this.scale = scale;
        this.se = se;
        this.layer = layer;
        Game1.CallDraw+=new SigDraw(Draw);
    } 
    #endregion

    #region Drawing
    public virtual void Draw()
    {
        Game1.spriteBatch.Draw(tex, Pos, rec, color, Rot, org, scale, se, layer);
    }
```

Comment: Presumably you're using some kind of offset vector to render the background, or you're doing something wit the viewport? Else it **will** be 0,0. Screenshots don't help us here, we need to see some code.

Comment: "its not (0,0) because the character is moving." That bit makes no sense to me. It should still be 0,0.

Comment: try changing your scale to 0? zoom = 0? in your update your also doing, translation * rotation * scale * translation... order of multiplication matters.

Comment: the problem is that (0, 0) point is the top-left of the terrain...
i need the top-left of my point of view... like in the picture based on the terrain's (0, 0). it needs to be updated everytime the character moves. tell me what code u need\

Comment: and its not 0, 0 because the camera follows the character

Comment: if you did  translation * translation * rotation * scale. does that change anything?

Comment: Just grab the vector of your camera, setting zoom etc. back to zero before doing so.

Answer (score 0):

If its control then you pass the control get the point object

```
private static Point FindLocation(Control ctrl)
{
Point p;
for (p = ctrl.Location; ctrl.Parent != null; ctrl = ctrl.Parent)
    p.Offset(ctrl.Parent.Location);
return p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to 0,0 origins you have 3 types you have Model, Worldview and Viewport and its dependent on which part of your code you are trying to reach it in.

If you are looking for 0,0 on a model it will point to the top left of the model. If you are looking for 0,0 on the worldview it will be bottom left of your area (map) and if you are looking for viewport 0,0 it will be up in the top left.

You are currently using the Model to find your position on the world view. Instead try storing and using your viewport position on your world and set your model/character position relative to that.

Without knowing any of the code it will be difficult for anyone to help directly.

Comment: t (0, 0) point is the top-left of the terrain... i need the top-left of my point of view... like in the picture based on the terrain's (0, 0). it needs to be updated everytime the character moves. tell me what code u need\

Comment: Ok so I presume you have a rectangle or position that stores the position of where your view is on the terrain. This is your viewport and this will be the 0,0 of your view(the screens 0,0). If you need help we need at least the part of code where you are outputting the display (ie the part where you are drawing the terrain and the character). Looking at your camera you have your 0,0 with vp.x and vp.y

Comment: i added the drawing class, is it ok?
and yea, i was looking for the screens(0, 0) like you wrote in your comment. i just dont find any rec that stores the viewport details or what u said there

Comment: Yeah that's not overly clear what you are using for what but its fine. The best way to get and keep viewport 0,0 is to position your camera (store the camera position separately) then use that to determine your character sprites position. So you have your terrain drawn 0,0 for that will be your world view origin. Upon this you draw your viewport using your cameras x,y position as origin. after this you add the position of your character sprite 0,0 for that being the position within the viewport. This would make your screens 0,0 the cameras x,y position

Comment: Reread your code and it looks like what you are trying to do is find the position your camera should be in. If that's not the problem then the camera position IS your viewports 0,0 as unless you have a zoom effect done post drawing the viewport is always what the camera sees, and that should be top left of the screen. If its not then the camera has somehow become inverted and will be at the bottom instead.